# React Router Doesn't Work on Safari and Firefox but Works on Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, safari, react-router

I am using React Router on my website to link to other pages. On Google Chrome, when I click on a link to another page within the website (through React Router), it works just fine. However, on Firefox, I have to click twice (after my first click, the current page refreshes, but after the second click, the new page loads). On Safari, it just keeps refreshing the current page.

How do I get React Router to work on the first click on Firefox and Safari?

You can try it out yourself on Safari link http://riceappsv2.surge.sh/. Scroll halfway down to where you see 5 circles with AirBNB logos, and try clicking on the link that says "BeakSpeak". It should link to this page http://riceappsv2.surge.sh/beakspeak.

Here is our App.JS. The 5 AirBNB logos are in the page called Projects. (The import statements are just for the pages that I load.)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ParallaxProvider } from 'react-scroll-parallax';
import LandingPage from './Pages/LandingPage.js';
import Testimonials from './Pages/Testimonials.js'
import WorkForUs from './Pages/WorkForUs.js';
import JoinUs from './Pages/JoinUs.js';
import Projects from './Pages/Projects.js';
import AboutUs from './Pages/AboutUs.js';
import WhatWeDo from './Pages/WhatWeDo.js';
import Partners from './Pages/Partners.js';
import './App.css';
import './hamburgers.css';
import './styles.css'
import ScrollIntoView from 'react-scroll-into-view';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ParallaxProvider>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div id="home"><LandingPage /></div>
          <div id="whatWeDo"><WhatWeDo /></div>
          <div id="aboutUs"><AboutUs /></div>
          <div id="projects"><Projects /></div>
          <div id="partners"><Partners /></div>
          <div id="testimonials"><Testimonials /></div>
          <div id="contactUs"><JoinUs /></div>
          <div id="joinUs"><WorkForUs /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </ParallaxProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Projects page in which I use React Router to link to the page BeakSpeak.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';
import './Projects.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default class LandingPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
    <div className = "projectsPageWrapper">
     <Fade left duration = {1500}>
        <div id = "beakspeak">
          <div id = "BsTitle">
          <Router>
            <div>
              <Link to = "/beakspeak" onClick = {() => window.location.reload()} class = "link">
                <h1>Beakspeak</h1>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </Router>
          </div>
          <div className = "circle">
            <img className = "airbnb" src = "http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/airbnb-logo-belo-880x628.png" alt=""></img>
            <div className = "projectText">
            Anonymous social media platform exclusively for the Rice community</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fade>
    </div>
  )
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You only seem to use React Router for a `Router` and a `Link`, in which to manually reload the page when clicking? Do you use more of it in other places or your app?

Comment: Are you running the latest versions of those browsers? Have you tried changing `BrowserRouter` to `HashRouter`?

Comment: Also I don't understand what this is for `onClick = {() => window.location.reload()}`. That will reload the browser, which seems to be what Firefox is doing as intended.

Comment: @KenoClayton I am running the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. I changed to HashRouter and the routing stopped working at all on Chrome and Firefox. (it was originally working in Chrome, not working at all in Safari, and took 2 clicks in Firefox to work)

Comment: @KenoClayton for your second question, if I get rid of ```onClick = {() => window.location.reload()}```, then when I click on a React Router link, the URL in the browser changes, but the new page does not load until I manually refresh the browser. That's why I include the code to automatically refresh the browser.

Comment: @Tholle I'm trying to change the url as well as the page. I'd be 100% open to a better way. I use it to open the 4 other projects pages, and to redirect back to the homepage from each projects page, but nothing else.

Comment: It's supposed to load as long as you have your `Routes` defined properly. Have you set up your routes?

Comment: Be sure to check up on the official docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic. Your routes should match any path that you wish to render, and provide a component to render if the path matches that.